# Design pattern to guarantee only one Runnable object of particular id value is being executed by the pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, grouping

Suppose I have an ordered list of `Runnable` objects that are to be executed by `ExecutorService`. My `Runnable` objects have a `userID` filed - let's say I have about **20** different `userId`-s and **10** is the number of threads in the pool (`ExecutorService` object).

What is a general design pattern to ensure that at most 1 `Runnable` object of particular group is being executed in one of threads at one time? (The goal is that all `Runnable` from one id group should be executed cronologically and synchronously).

Comment: Well, I do have one idea of a solution, including map with id-s as keys and arrays of Runnable as values, adding flags indincating whether one id is now being processed and so on... Just wonder if there is any straightforward solution.

Comment: you are using a ThreadPoolExecutor, right?

Comment: Yes, I use a ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create queues for each group and when a task terminates you read the corresponding queue and submit the next task if needed.

For that you somehow need to identify when a Runnable terminates. With the standard JDK classes you cannot really do that in a simple way but using the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library you can wrap your ExecutorService into a ListeningExecutorService. If you submit a task through this wrapper it will return you a [ListenableFuture](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) instead of the plain Java Future. A ListenableFuture will let you register callbacks that will be executed when the task terminates. In these callbacks you can check your queues and submit the next tasks in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

For each Id, you need a lightweight SerialExecutor like one described in [JavaDocs of Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). That implementation is not optimal - for each input task, it creates additional service Runnable. Opimized version can be found at https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/main/java/actor/serialexec/SerialExecutor.java, where SerialExecutor serves as intermediate Runnable and resubmits itself when it is idle and a new task appears.

Comment: Thank you for your interest! Unfortunately, this answer is not 100% clear for me - why (exactly) this would be a good solution for me? As far as I understand, *For each Id, I need a lightweight SerialExecutor* which means I may have **20** different SerialExecutors, each of which may be running its own Runnable at a time => I do not control the number of threads running (In my post I mention I want to limit their number, let's say to **10** -> the point is 10<20).

Comment: because you want at most 1 Runnable object of particular group being executed at a time. This means Runnables of particular group must be organized in a separate queue, and that queue processed each time when a new Runnable appear and when execution of next Runnable finishes. This is exactly what SerialExecutor does.