# How can I create a thread pool in Java that does not run certain tasks concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to submit tasks to a thread pool (or executor service) but task should not be executed concurrently if there's already one task in the executor with the same key.

Specifically, this is for a build tool, to prevent tasks for the same part of a source tree executing concurrently.

This is an example of why I would want this behaviour:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        Path resource = Paths.get("tmp");

        service.submit(() -> {
            Files.write(resource, Collections.singleton("foo"));
            Thread.sleep(10);

            if (!new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource)).equals("foo")) {
                System.err.println("someone changed my stuff");
            }


            return null;
        });
        service.submit(() -> Files.write(resource, Collections.singleton("bar")));
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: Why not to use Single thread which all incoming threads will be in queue and execute as soon as current running thread will complete `final ExecutorService exService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`

Comment: This sounds like a good idea - but I'm not sure this is possible, because this is not about unexpected behaviour (which I could provide an example of), but a capability that I don't believe exists in the classes and code of default JRE. I'll do my best and tell me what you think.

Comment: I specifically want to run multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a separate single-threaded executor for each key. Since there can exist many keys, creating a thread for each key can be expensive, and so we replace single-threaded executor with a light-weight `SerialExecutor` which behaves like a single-threaded executor but have no own thread, borrowing a thread from some normal backend executor when needed. `SerialExecutor` is described in [JavaDocs of Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). Opimized version can be found at my [CodeSamples project](https://github.com/rfqu/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/simpleactor/SerialExecutor.java),

See similar question [Design pattern to guarantee only one Runnable object of particular id value is being executed by the pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888226/design-pattern-to-guarantee-only-one-runnable-object-of-particular-id-value-is-b/21899829#21899829)

Answer (score 0):

Try with 2 different executers for your different type of tasks and if first pool completed then start another one.

```
ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     Runnable worker = new FirstTask("" + i);
         executor1.execute(worker);
     }
     executor1.shutdown();

  while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }

ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         Runnable worker = new AnotherTask("" + i);
             executor2.execute(worker);
    }
    executor2.shutdown();
```